# pass a controller parameter to a view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, uiviewcontroller, viewdata

What is the best way to passing a controller parameter to a view? The parameter is not related to any model, so cant do strongly typed view.

Controller:

```
        public ActionResult DisplayParam(string id, string name)
    {
       return View();
    }
```

View:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage" %>
```

<%@ Import NameSpace="System.IO" %>
<%@ Import NameSpace="System" %>
<%@ Import NameSpace="System.Data" %>
<%@ Import NameSpace="System.Web" %>
<%@ Import NameSpace="System.Text" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="MY.Controllers" %>

Controller Parameter

```
<div>
Controller Parameter id: @id
Controller Parameter name: @name
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way is to use a view model:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

and then have your controller action populate this view model and pass it to the view, just like this:

```
public ActionResult DisplayParam(string id, string name)
{
    var model = new MyViewModel
    {
        Id = id,
        Name = name
    };
    return View(name);
}
```

and finally you would have your view strongly typed to this view model and use the information to display it:

```
<%@ Page 
    Language="C#" 
    Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<AppName.Models.MyViewModel>" 
%>
<div>
    Controller Parameter id: <%= Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Id) %>
    Controller Parameter name: <%= Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Name) %>
</div>
```

or if you were using the Razor view engine:

```
@model AppName.Models.MyViewModel
<div>
    Controller Parameter id: @Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Id)
    Controller Parameter name: @Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Name)
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Darin, I still dont see the parameters in my view. I dont see any errors either. When I add a watch on "Id" and "Name" in the DisplayParam ActionResult, I dont see the paramater values passed to it. I see the view but no parameter values in it. Just the labels

Comment: Here is my view model:
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace Student.Models
{
    public class StudentViewModel
    {

        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
 
    }
}

Comment: Here is my controller Action:
        public ActionResult DisplayStudent(string id, string name)
        {
            var model = new StudentViewModel
            //{
                Id = id,
                Name = name
              };

           return View();
        }

Comment: Here is my view:
<%@ Page Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<Student.Models.StudentViewModel>" %>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >

<body>

    <div>
    Student Id: <%= Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Id) %>
    Student Name: <%= Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Name) %>
    </div>

</body>
</html>

Comment: Actually the Parameter values are passed to the DisplayParam ActionResult but not displayed in the view

Comment: @user793468, you must pass the view model in your controller action when returning the view: `return View(model);` and not `return View();`. Notice the difference?

Comment: Darin, Is there a way to pass these (id and name) parameters to a different controller action from my view on button click?

Comment: I got that to work as well. Now I want to pass a value from webform textarea to a controller action. 
What is the best way to passing a textarea value from a webform to a controller?